# how to get facebook search results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, rfacebook, social-graph

I am trying to build a network of people that match a search criteria on FB and get their friends. All public information of course, or at least accessible to my own account. Say I search for the name "Smith".
I want to get all the people that match that query, then search in their connections all those names that match "Smith" and the relationship to each others and so on. This way I create clusters of the various interconnected "Smith"(es).

I am fluent with `R` and so I tried the `Rfacebook` package. There is a function there called `searchFacebook` but it does not work anymore, because the API search was disabled by Facebook itself. for info I get:

`Searching for posts was deprecated with version 2.0 of the Facebook Graph API.`

What options do I have in this case? Is this even possible?

The language is not an issue, I can use Python too. I just used R cause it's faster for me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about Python? Should I post a python solution that works?

Comment: yes! that would work too :) but I think the problem is the facebook API. I use R just because i'm more fluent in it.

Comment: Alright—it might take me an hour or two to get home (on commute there currently). Do you currently have python installed? What OS do you have?

Comment: Yes, I have anaconda. I'm on windows 10, but i have ubuntu too. Take your time, not in a hurry.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is not possible at all. the search api is very limited and i am not sure why you would use the (deprecated) post api instead of using the user search api? take a look at the docs.